# Space availability issue

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I am using SQlserver2005. My database are becomeing very large and space is becoming very sparse.

Please suggest what to do? (apart from buying space)

Answer (score 0):

- Or you have DB recovery model = FULL and not backing up the transaction log
- or you have very long-running huge transactions
- or you perform massive inserts-deletes with GHOST CLEANUP process switched down
- or it is all ok and it is your natural load and data grow behavior

Comment: last one it is all ok i mean all the above are ok and it is natural load and data grow behaviuor then?

Comment: just add a new volume and then add data/log files to the database.